# Adding percentage in python - xlwt / pyexcelerator

Tags: python, xlwt, pyexcelerator

just a quick question, how to add percent sign to numbers without modifying number. I have tried format percent with myStyleFont.num_format_str = '0.00%' but it multiplies with 100 but I need just to append percent.

Ty in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note carefully: "modifying" and "multiplies with 100" affect the displayed result, they  affect neither the value stored in the file nor the value used in formula calculations.

The technique of making an operator be treated as a literal is known as "escaping".

The escape character in Excel number format strings is the backslash.

To do what you want, your format should be `r"0.00\%"` or `"0.00\\%"`

The above is a property of Excel, not restricted to Python or `xlwt` etc. You can test this using one of the UIs (Excel, OpenOffice Calc, Gnumeric).

Note that unless you have a restricted set of users who will read and understand the documentation that you will write [unlikely * 3], you shouldn't do that; it will be rather confusing -- the normal Excel user on seeing `5.00%` assumes that the underlying number is `0.05`. To see this, in Excel etc type these into A1, A2, A3: `5%` then `.05` then `=A1=A2` ... you will see `TRUE` in A3.

`pyExcelerator` is abandonware; why do you mention it???

About `myStyleFont.num_format_str = '0.00%'` (1) "font" and "num_format_str" are quite independent components of a style aka XF; your variable name "myStyleFont" is confused/confusing. (2) Setting up XFs by poking attributes into objects is old hat in `xlwt`; use `easyxf` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify to anyone, here is an example of formatting a number as a percentage in xlwt:

```
from xlwt import easyxf, Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Formatting Sheet')
style_percent = easyxf(num_format_str='0.00%')
ws.write(0, 5, 0.12, style_percent)
```

This shows in the Excel cell as '12.00%'.

Answer (score 1):

The `00.0%` number format expects percentages, so multiplying by 100 to display it is the correct behavior.  To get the results you want, you could either put the data in the cell as a string in whatever format you choose or you could divide by 100.0 before you store the value in the cell.

Comment: Awesome. Sometimes we forget the basics of mathematics. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Do this**

> ***Divide the value by 100 before applying format style '0.00%' to it***

```
style = XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = '0.00%'

new_val = '502.22'
sheet = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
sheet.write(num, 1, new_val/100, style)

wb.save('sample.xls')
```

I hope this helps your purpose.